# Format DateTime string representation in GridView dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

Just looking for some strategies to modify the typical

mm/dd/yy 00:00:00  to simply 
mm/dd/yy of a datetime item being returned in a dataset that is bound to the gridview

thanks

the item is within a dataset and I am simply doing the following

```
gridview.DataSource = GetDataSet();
gridview.DataBind();
```

So I don't have a ton of interaction with the dataset at the moment. I could brute force iterate through it and do something like

```
foreach(Table)
   foreach(Row)
      grab date Col, format and concat to look as desired
```

but this is very messy and was wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just specify the DataFormatString in the GridView

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" DataField="MyDate" 
     DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yy}">
```

Comment: I knew there had to be something sexy like this. TY sir

Comment: to clarify, I looked up the property and you could just do the following: DataFormatString="{0:d}" but thank you again sir!

Comment: Its matter of preference, I prefer to make it explicit, so that the next programmer who looks at this code for maintenenace need not do the `look up`!

Comment: You have a valid point ;) 1 vote for that. I have a co-worker who makes a habit of creating hardly maintainable code so I am all for that.