# Get gridview cell DataFormatString

Tags: asp.net, gridview

How can I get applied DataFormatString of perticular cell of gridview? I am looping through all cells of gridview and I need to check dataformatstring of the cell. Any way to get it?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Kindly put what you have tried so far.

Comment: are you using bound field.

Comment: yes i have added columns using boundfield dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the DataFormatString in the GridView

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" DataField="MyDate" 
     DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yy}">
```

Further reading

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx

### More links

[datetime format in asp.net gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235324/datetime-format-in-asp-net-gridview)
[Format DateTime string representation in GridView dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342657/format-datetime-string-representation-in-gridview-dataset)
[DataFormatString not working in gridview column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207693/dataformatstring-not-working-in-gridview-column)

Comment: I do not want to set DataFormatString but i need to get the DataFormatString.

Comment: @QAÅøæÅøæ what is the data type of your field?

Comment: For some columns it is int and for some it is money some places it is date.

Comment: @QAÅøæÅøæ for which column you want `DataFormatString`